# Extranatural transformations are a special case of dinatural transformations

Tags: category-theory, natural-transformations

Recently I have been trying to understand extranatural and dinatural transformations. Here are the definitions I am working with.

From the [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extranatural+transformation):

> Let $F:A\times B\times B^{op}\to D$ and $G:A\times C\times C^{op}\to D$ be functors. A family of morphisms
> $$\{\alpha_{a,b,c}: F(a,b,b) \to G(a,c,c)\}_{a\in A,b\in B,c\in C} $$
> is said to be ordinary natural in $a$ and extra-natural in $b,c$ if
>
> 1. Ordinary naturality in $a$: For all $b\in B, c\in C$ and morphisms $f:a\to a'$ in $A$, we have $\alpha_{a',b,c} \circ F(f,1,1) = G(f,1,1) \circ \alpha_{a,b,c}$
> 2. Extranaturality in $b$: For all $a\in A, c\in C$ and  morphisms $g:b\to b'$ in $B$, we have $\alpha_{a,b,c} \circ F(1,1,g) = \alpha_{a,b',c}\circ F(1,g,1)$
> 3. Extranaturality in $c$: For all $a\in A, b\in B$ and  morphisms $h:c\to c'$ in $C$, we have $G(1,h,1)\circ \alpha_{a,b,c} = G(1,1,h)\circ \alpha_{a,b,c'}$

Also from the [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dinatural+transformation):

> Let $F,G: C^{op}\times C \to D$ be functors. A dinatural transformation from $F$ to $G$ is a collection of morphisms $\alpha_c: F(c,c) \to G(c,c)$ such that for every morphism $f: c\to c'$ in $C$, we have $$G(1_c,f)\circ \alpha_c\circ F(f,1_c) = G(f,1_{c'}) \circ \alpha_{c'}\circ F(1_{c'},f)$$

Both of the above pages (and Wikipedia) claim that dinatural transformations generalise extranatural transformations, or in other words that extranatural transformations are a special case of dinatural transformations. However, I am struggling to see how this can be true. For example, for a dinatural transformation the domains of the functors $F$ and $G$ must be equal but for an extranatural transformation they do not. The most explicit description of the comparison given I can find is given [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02503), where it is shown in Proposition 1.1.12 that an extranatural transformation $\alpha$ between $F,G: C\times C\times C^{op} \to D$ gives rise to a dinatural transformation between certain $F',G': A\times A^{op} \to D$ where $A:= C\times C^{op}\times C^{op}$. However, this only handles a special case for the domain of $F,G$.

---

My questions are as follows:

1. Can the process described in Proposition 1.1.12 be extended to the case of $F: \mathcal{A}\times \mathcal{B}\times\mathcal{B}^{op}\to \mathcal{D}$, $G: \mathcal{A}\times \mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{C}^{op}\to \mathcal{D}$?
2. If so, how?
3. If not, why does one run into the unqualified statement that "extranatural is a special case of dinatural" so much? Is it because the special case of functors with domain $C\times C\times C^{op}$ is especially important?

Comment: Question $(1)$ is not a full sentence, I have no idea what you mean. Because of this, questions $(2)$ and slightly question $(3)$ don't make sense either. "If so" - what is the "so"?

Comment: @FShrike Thank you for pointing out the typo, fixed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\A}{\mathcal{A}}\newcommand{\B}{\mathcal{B}}\newcommand{\C}{\mathcal{C}}\newcommand{\D}{\mathcal{D}}\newcommand{\E}{\mathcal{E}}\newcommand{\op}{{^{\mathsf{op}}}}$Fix $\A,\B,\C,\D$ and functors $F:\A\times\B\times\B\op\to\D,\,G:\A\times\C\times\C\op\to\D$.

Define $\E:=\A\times\B\times\C$. I will define two functors $F':\E\op\times\E\to\D,\,G':\E\op\times\E\to\D$ such that dinatural transformations $F'\to G'$ correspond to extranatural transformations $F\to G$.

$F'((a',b',c'),(a,b,c)):=F(a,b,b')$ and $G'((a',b',c'),(a,b,c)):=G(a,c,c')$ on objects; there is an obvious extension on arrows. It is a good and straightforward exercise to show my claim; there is a canonical bijection between dinatural $F'\to G'$ and extranatural $F\to G$.

Hint: It is actually very easy to actually define the corresponding extranatural transformation, given a dinatural transformation, and vice versa; if you're having trouble with that you're overthinking. Write down explicitly what the domain and codomain of these arrows should be in both cases. Then what remains to do is check these arrows actually are (extra, di)natural. To do so; I defined $F',G'$ essentially by taking some *projections* and then applying $F$ and $G$. Think about direct sums and components, you want to "pad your vector with zeroes", whatever that means, to prove the (di)(extra)naturality statements.

Comment: Thanks, this should have been more obvious than it was. Is there any reason one would chose to use the category $C\times C^{op}\times C^{op}$ (as in the reference in my question) rather than $C\times C\times C$ or is it just an aesthetic choice?

Comment: @ducksforever I think you will need to have the contravariance appear somewhere. If you force the "bits" that go $\mathcal{C}^{\mathsf{op}}\to\mathcal{D}$ to instead be defined on $\mathcal{C}$, now the codomain must be $\mathcal{D}^{\mathsf{op}}$ which conflicts with the codomain of the other components. I don't think you can define a functor $\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ *in general* that does the job

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your reply so let me try to make my question more clear: In your answer, you set $\mathcal{E} = \mathcal{A}\times \mathcal{B}\times\mathcal{C}$. Specialising to the case where $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{B}=\mathcal{C}$, this becomes $\mathcal{E} = \mathcal{C}\times \mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{C}$. What i'm wondering is whether there is a specific reason that in the linked reference they seem to have instead taken $\mathcal{E} = \mathcal{C}\times \mathcal{C}^{op}\times\mathcal{C}^{op}$?

Comment: @ducksforever Oh, I misunderstood your comment. I thought you wanted a functor from $C\times C\times C$ not from $(C\times C\times C)op\times(C\times C\times C)$. The difference between that and use of $C\times Cop\times Cop$ is purely aesthetic because there is a permutation isomorphism between the two categories $Eop\times E$ that just rearranges the arguments and preserves all (di)(extra)naturals

Comment: In the answer, I think it is cleaner if one sets $\mathcal{E} := \mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B} \times \mathcal{C}^{\mathsf{op}}$. Then one can directly see the required commutativity of the hexagonal diagram for a dinatural transformation (as in Loregian's (Co)end Calculus book, Definition 1.1.1) using the commutativity coming from the extranatural transformation. (This is perhaps what's being alluded to in the comments above, but I write this here for the non-expert like me.)